# The script conflicts with the layout alignment of my responsive template.. How I can fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, blogspot

I copied and customized one script taken from a past stackoverflow discussion. And now I can prevent the "Print screen" with the current key combinations: "ctrl+alt+printscr" , "ctrl+printscr" and "alt+printscr". But after I saved my blogger template, I did some tests with great resoults: the script really works great.. But not as expected, I encountered two problems:

1. If I click the address bar or leave the page unactive, the script automatically show the background image to cover the layout.
2. If I try to resize the window, the alignment of the elements fails..

I'm not expert with the javascript language, so probably I made some sort of mistake. I made a picture to show you the nature of the problem.

PS: My layout is totally responsive and I never got problems with the automatic alignment of the elements. Then I tried to remove the latest javascript and again works perfectly. Probably I made some unknown mistake into the code.

[I installed many anti-stealing protection scripts, jquery and css (but they not conflict apparently..) Here is a screen demostration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5xrW.png)

Here is the code:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function copyToClipboard() {
  // Create a &quot;hidden&quot; input
  var aux = document.createElement(&quot;input&quot;);
  // Assign it the value of the specified element
  aux.setAttribute(&quot;value&quot;, &quot;You can no longer give printscreen. This is part of the new system security measure.&quot;);
  // Append it to the body
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  // Highlight its content
  aux.select();
  // Copy the highlighted text
  document.execCommand(&quot;copy&quot;);
  // Remove it from the body
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
  alert(&quot;Print screen disabled.&quot;);
}

$(window).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 44){
    copyToClipboard();
  }
}); 

$(window).focus(function() {
  $(&quot;body&quot;).show();
}).blur(function() {
  $(&quot;body&quot;).hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: *"I not send the link because I installed many anti-stealing protection scripts,"* - Yes, we're all lining up to steal your code. *"And now I can prevent the "Print screen" with the current key combinations..."* - Why bother? The user can work around this, most simply by just pressing `PrntScr` by itself.

Comment: Just a few points: First, it’s `<script type="text/javascript">`. What you have there is _very_ out of date. Second, you’re copy & paste didn’t work: you have a lot of `&quot;` codes. Third, if you fill your JavaScript with code to make things as difficult as possible for your users, you’re not likely to get an enthusiastic response.

Comment: @Manngo hello, anyway I always used these type of syntax. I don't know If blogspot is compatible with modern ways to write the code. But, requires to change the "&quot;&quot;" instead of the "&&". It doesn't accept the code as you described.

Comment: If you're that sensitive about someone stealing this ridiculous snippet of JavaScript and print screening, you are probably in the wrong profession. Also, **"&quot;&quot;"** !== **"&&"**

Comment: Ok, anyway can you help me with these ridiculous snippet of javascript? ._.

Comment: @DanWhite I prefer to prevent the stealing of the contents what I publish in my posts. I got public things, but also a private category with things of my daily life. Anyway, because I really work hard for on my project I want to reduce the possibilities to any intentional stealer. If someone is able to copy the post for me its ok, but I don't want to all the potential user can copy my contents without to cite me as originary a author. Why all you guys want to judge me for my personal preference? I don't think is respectful.